# Can we use the media property in HTML while linking to a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that when we link CSS files in HTML, we can use `media` to load different Stylesheets depending on certain things, can we do this while linking to scripts? Here is my HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css" media="(min-width: 808px)" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 807px)" type="text/css" />
    <script media="(min-width: 808px)" src = "scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script media="(max-width: 807px)" src = "scripts/mobile.js"></script>
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [specification for `script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) doesn't list `media` as one of the supported attributes. And if you think about it, for that particular example, what is the browser supposed to do if, after loading the page when the width was 850px and running the `script.js` file, the user resizes the window to 600px wide? It can't undo what `script.js` did.

But if you were testing for something that wouldn't change, you could use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to determine which script to load dynamically. ([Reasonably supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia), including the last several releases of iOS Safari and Android's built-in browser and the latest release of most mobile browsers, but not IE9 or earlier, or Opera Mini.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
var winCurrWidth = $(window).width();
```

If window resize happens, just add:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   winCurrWidth = $(window).width();
});
```

Now start wirting like this:

```
if(winCurrWidth < 808){
  //Do Something..
}
else{
  //Do something else..
}
```